# Get the IP address of the server from SQL in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to check the current connection to validate if the configuration is correct according to the environment. I mean, I have a ETL and I want to be sure the database configuration points to the right server (dev, QA or prod)

How can I get the IP address of the server or hostname from SQL in Teradata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Teradata system might have multiple nodes there's a range of IP addresses assigned to a system. And the hostname is used in your connection string, thus it should be known in advance.

There's no builtin way to get that info from a system table, but it's easy to create a SQL-UDF:

```
FUNCTION syslib.#servername ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 'dev';

GRANT EXECUTE FUNCTION ON syslib.#servername TO PUBLIC;
```

As it's stored in `syslib` it can be used without qualified name: `select servername()`